# How to integrate twitter with the help of Twitter+Auth API in iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter

I am integrating twitter in iphone by using twitter+auth API, in this API what i set the call back url during the generating the consumer and consumer secret key. Please help me

Comment: Need more information. What is that twitter+auth API? Could you show your code and how you tried to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a complete tutorial to integrate twitter+oauth to your application

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

Use share kit

http://getsharekit.com/