# a simple tutorial for implementing twitter in my iphone application

Tags: iphone, twitter

i searched alot also looked on stack over flow , so please don't make this duplicate question,
I am not able to find a simple and complete tutiorial for implementing the twitter for iphone ,
please help

Comment: You seriously couldn't find anything? [SO Search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+twitter+tutorial) one of the results has a link to a [complete tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129320/how-to-integrate-twitter-with-the-help-of-twitterauth-api-in-iphone-application) which links to [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/) That took longer to type in this comment than it did to find!

Comment: implementing what? posting? searching? timeline? profile? images? -1

Answer (score 0):

I have used google and found some:

1. http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=1303
2. http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/09/integrating-twitter-into-your-applications/
3. https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController

hope this works for you !